# How to write a reusable component/module?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, reusability, angular-components, angular-module

I'm writing currently two new websites. Both share a lot of functionality. Is it possible with angular to write little components/modules and to reuse them in other apps? What would be the project structure for it or can I use the structure of the ng-cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I guess it would be possible as you get a lot of angular2 plugins where you npm install something and include it in your own project. If I was looking so have some sort shared components project I would have look at something like this and copy their project structure and how they have it set up. https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr. That is just one example and there are lot of other third party plugins which you can use for inspiration.